# How to build API to a project using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I want to build the API for a project using ruby on rails with already existing db (mysql). How can i do it? Can any one help me?

Comment: [Here's a good read](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_two).

Comment: ok.. will go through it.

Comment: Hey Vucko.. The code in link provided is in ruby on rail v5 or other version?!

Comment: Any one help i need it in latest version of ruby on rails..